# How to extract string from a filename containing date using regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 version

I have a string as below:

flow_id="Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19"

I am getting flow_id from a function, so now I want to extract Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment, I want something like below :

if flow_id contains "YYYY-MM-DD"

clean_flow_id=re.sub('\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}','',flow_id)

but the output of clean_flow_id is 'Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_'
I don't want last '_'

So to conclude first I need to match if the string contains date like "YYYY_MM_DD" if yes then extract the name as given above, can anyone please help?

I cannot find a function or library to match flow_id with date format ("YYYY_MM_DD")
to get clean_flow_id I tried something like below :

clean_flow_id=re.sub('\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}','',flow_id)

clean_flow_id='Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_'

import re

flow_id="Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19"
if flow_id

Expected :
clean_flow_id=flow_id=Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment

I expect the output of clean_flow_id to be Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment, but the actual output is Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_

Could you please in finding function to match date format in flow_id?

Comment: Can you add a `_` to the start of your regex?

Comment: yes that solves the issue thanks, but still, I need to find a pattern to match date ( YYYY_MM_DD) in flow_id ?

Comment: If it is always at the end of the string you could use re.sub with `_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}$` and replace with an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/2aU1zs/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) in your if statement:

```
test = re.search('(.*)_\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}', flow_id)
if test:
    your_match = test[1]
```

test[0] is the whole string

test[1] is the first parentheses

test[2] is the date (as a string)

--

Edit

```
def get_clean_flow_id(filename):
    test = re.search('(.*)_\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}', filename)
    if test:
        return test[1]
    else:
        return None
```

Returns:

```
>>> get_clean_flow_id("Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19.csv")
'Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment'
>>> get_clean_flow_id("Omada_weekly_fle_20190319120301.csv")
>>> get_clean_flow_id("tivity_weekly_fle_20190319120301.json")
>>>
```

Comment: This might work, but I cannot hardcode anything to compare since I will use this expression to match other files as well

Comment: Can you explain that a little more? Do you mean you can't hardcode the regex? What are some of the other file examples?

Comment: I am taking the base filename from a path and storing into a variable get_flow_id , so we have many files like : Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19.csv
Omada_weekly_fle_20190319120301.csv
tivity_weekly_fle_20190319120301.json so only YYYY_MM_DD file format is not correct so I need regex function to extract the value for rest of the file it is taken care in get_flow_id function in the code..that is why I need a if condition to check the file date pattern if it contion "YYYY_MM_DD" then I need to extract the flow id otherwise it should procced further

Comment: I think I understand. My code will basically ignore any filenames that are not in the "YYYY_MM_DD" - the `if test` only returns True if there's a match. I'll edit it to look more like a function.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this simple expression returns the desired output:

```
(.*?)_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}\b
```

With `re.sub` you can simply replace it with `\1`.

#### Test with `re.sub`

```
import re

expression = r"(.*?)_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}\b"

string = """
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_01_01
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_3_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_111


"""

print(re.sub(expression, r"\1", string))
```

#### Output

```
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_3_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_111
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

expression = r"(.*?)_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}\b"

string = """
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_01_01
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_3_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_1
Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_111


"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment', 'Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uf9fo0/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/uf9fo0/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### Test if there is a date

```
import re

expression = r"^(?=.*\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}).*$"
string = "Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19"

if re.search(expression, string):
    print(f"There is at least one date in the {string}")
else:
    print(f"Sorry! {string} has no date.")
```

#### Output

```
There is at least one date in the Livongo_Weekly_Enrollment_2019_03_19
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CuvfDt/1/)

Comment: Thanks, Emma, but  this clean_flow_id=re.sub('[_]\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}','',flow_id) also give me expected result , but can you please help me to match a pattern like ("YYYY_MM_DD") in flow id

Comment: Like if flow_id contains "YYYY_MM_DD" then only clean it

Comment: yes, in the code nothing is hardcoded, I am getting flow_id from a function after getting the value of that function I need to check if flow_id contain pattern like "YYYY_MM_DD" if yes then do the following if NO then continues without doing anything.